# Putting a delay between frames in DirectX

Tags: c++, 3d, directx, delay, direct3d

I recently started learning DirectX programming in C++ and I've encountered a minor problem.

The thing is that my excercise requires me to change colors in a DirectX application from one to another. I have a function which does that:

```
void render_frame(void)
{
    // start the random generator
    srand(time(NULL));

    // clear the window to random color
    d3ddev->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(rand() % 255, rand() % 255, rand() % 255), 1.0f, 0);

    // begin/end/display scene
    d3ddev->BeginScene();
    d3ddev->EndScene();
    d3ddev->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}
```

It works, but it's dependant on the time() delay and I wonder if there's a better counterpart in Direct3D library. For example if I could call this function in order with specific color and delay in chain like this:

```
void render_frame_red(void);
delay(1000);
void render_frame_blue(void);
delay(1000);
```

I know that function Sleep() exists in standard library, but it literally freezes my application window (I can't interact with it during the delay). Maybe I can set time to different tickrate so it'll update as frequently as I want it to?

I know it's a small thing and I would probably figure it out later on my journey with 3D programming, but it wouldn't hurt if I knew more about how things work in DirectX.

Comment: Only ever call srand() once in a program.

Comment: Yes, that's my bad. I usually call it at the start of my main() function (WinMain() in this case).

Comment: @NeilButterworth Actually once in a thread. Or even use `::std::random_device`. As for question, DirectX does not deal with time at all. All the related functionality now exists in DXGI (see [IDXGISwapChain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174569(v=vs.85).aspx) ) and system timers.

Answer (score 0):

The general model for Direct3D is to render frames "as fast as possible" and then have time-based operations in your program deal with animation. Traditional GDI-style drawing only paints 'on-demand', which you can do with Direct3D but makes things harder.

In other words, use clock-time instead of frame-count to control animation and effects. For a good timer solution for Direct3D rendering, see [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2014/12/03/understanding-game-time-revisited/).

> BTW, don't invest your time in learning legacy Direct3D 9 which relies heavily on supporting code from the deprecated DirectX SDK and requires the legacy DirectSetup to deploy the ancient helper library `D3DX9` (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx)). Use DirectX 11. See [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).

Comment: What's the main difference between these two? I know that DirectX SDK is no longer being updated, but aren't those based on the same roots? (syntax, communication with GPU, technologies etc.) Do contemporary developers use DirectX Tool Kit to make their games? I know I ask questions without basis, but I need to be sure before dropping my studies from deprecated SDK.

Comment: @RPAnimation `DirectX SDK` is updated quite frequently, but it became a part of `Windows SDK`. That separate `DirectX SDK` is a deprecated legacy SDK. `DirectX Tool Kit` is a pack of support libraries to simplify development (and it is also updated quite frequently).

Comment: There are dozens of posts about the status of the DirectX SDK on my blog on different topics. Start with the MSDN link above for context, then look at [the blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/tag/dxsdk/). Most game developers either use an existing game engine (which uses DirectX 11/12), or they already know DirectX well enough to write their own engine. I pointed out _DirectX Tool Kit_ as an accessible way to learn DirectX 11 in C++ based on supported, open-source libraries that avoids the use of the deprecated DirectX SDK. Most other tutorials online are outdated in this respect.

Comment: I did some research and you're right but I think I'll stick with what I've got for now. I'm just too overwhelmed by thought that I can finally draw something on screen, instead of analyzing long algorythms on my console. On top of that Frank D. Luna's book about DirectX really drew me into 3D Programming.